# How to get interval of X number of consecutive days and values from tables records and scores

Tags: php, mysql, sql, intervals

I am trying to get the average score of X number of consecutive dates (interval) from two tables. With this I mean the dates must be consecutive based on the value of column records.status (only if the status is T or P the row values are selected, especially scores.score).

For example if I select an interval of 4 consecutive dates for personid = 133*, i like to return the following (pre average calculation, which I think I should get with a SQL query?)

```
2015-07-11  5
2015-10-17  2
2015-11-06  5
2016-01-20  5

2016-01-30  4
2016-05-19  4
2016–09-07  1   
2016-09-28  3

2016-12-29  2
2017-01-17  1
2017-01-22  3
2017-04-02  2
```

and to plot a chart (after average calculation, which I think I need to do with PHP)

```
group 1 (2015-07-11 / 2016-01-20) 4.25
group 2 (2016-01-30 / 2016-09-28) 3.00
group 3 (2016-12-29 / 2017-04-02) 2.00
```

*Here is some sample data I randomly generated and I am testing with, but my actual data is bigger and is better structured with more columns and really consecutive dates (mo-fri, days right after eachother).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b7a62/1

Any tips, suggestions are really welcome.

MySQL version: 5.6.26 
[edit1] Somehow my sqlfiddle snippet is offline, but this should be my sample setup

```
————2 DB tables schema’s
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `records` (
  `person` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `purdate` date NOT NULL,
  `personid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `personid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) 

—-php for sample data—
function getRandomDateTime($startDate, $endDate, $num) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $dateArr[] = date('Y-m-d', mt_rand(strtotime($startDate), strtotime($endDate)));       
    }
    sort($dateArr, SORTDATE);// SORT_REGULAR);SORTDATE);//
    return $dateArr;

}
$test = getRandomDateTime('2015-06-03', '2017-05-12', 100);

echo "insert into records (person, status, purdate, personID) values\r\n";
foreach($test as $value) {
    $arrCode = ['P','L','T'];
    $arrId = [133, 145,156];
   $rand = $arrCode[array_rand($arrCode, 1)];
   $randID = $arrId[array_rand($arrId, 1)];
    echo "('person_name', '".$rand."', '".$value."', '".$randID."'),\r\n";
}

echo "insert into scores (personID, score) values\r\n";
for ($i=0;$i < 100;$i++) {
    $arrId = [133, 145,156];
    $randID = $arrId[array_rand($arrId, 1)];
    echo "('".$randID."','".rand(1,5)."'),\r\n";

}

——— SQL Query To Update The Date Column—
UPDATE scores  
SET scores.date = (  
SELECT records.purdate  
    FROM records  
    WHERE records.id = scores.id  
);
```

[edit2] And this simple php function, which I call like:. 
getConsecutiveInterval(4).

```
  function getConsecutiveInterval($interval) {
    global $conn;

//    $interval = 4;
    $offset = '';
// For loop will control the results sets divided by 4 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $interval; $i++) {
        // To add the offset after the first set
        if ($offset > 0) {
            $limitValues = $interval . ", " . $offset . " ";
        } else {
            $limitValues = $interval;
        }
// Query is the same and at the end of it you include LIMIT to be controlled by the loop.
        $q = "SELECT a.purdate, b.score, a.status "
                . "FROM records a "
                . "INNER JOIN scores2 b "
                . "ON a.purdate = b.date AND a.personid = b.personid "
                . "WHERE a.personid = 133 AND a.status IN('P','T') "
                . "ORDER BY purdate ASC, score DESC ";
        $sqlquery = $q . "  LIMIT " . $limitValues;
        $avg = 0;
        $total = 0;
    //Total Found Use To Divide by ... For Max Loop
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //end
        foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery) as $results) {
            // Do Something
            $total += $results['score'];
            $avg = $total / $interval;
        }
        echo $avg . '<br/>';
        $offset += $interval;
    } echo '<hr/>';
}
```

I am aware that random data outputs different average but based on my following random data and the hardcoded personid = 133

[image: based on my random sample data the query returns]

the average output I get with the PHP function
[image: averages outputs]

and I expect the averages to be `2.75, 3.5 and 3.5(based on the rest 2 dates not 4)`

And when I use getConsecutiveInterval(3); I expect the average value to be `3.33, 3.33, 2.66 and 4 (based on 1 date)`

Comment: You need to put sample data in the question, preferably as a table.  Your example in the question has one date, but your data has two.

Comment: What version of MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: @MattW. You have a problem with the SQL Fiddle?

Comment: ah I didn't see the link

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have made some sample data but it is correct that both tables have a column date which is equal and also a person id which is equal
GerardH.Pille i am using mysql 5.6.26 (I edited my question)

Comment: @user9191816 I've update my answer, accept my apology for this latency. I  got busy in work and I barely made it.

Comment: Wow @iSR5 , you really provided me with a lot of new stuff to learn and an amazing answer/solution. Again I have to admit I need to readup on the mysql possibilities, especially the stored procedure. Going to do that when I am fresh and awake. Tx for all your time,now!

Comment: @user9191816 glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
The previous examples that I gave you, helped me to understand your needs and your background knowledge (what do you prefer to develop on).

I know a PHP solution will work best for you, but you know that not all MySQL solutions should relay on PHP. So, I decided to go with the best method I could think of.

I've got the samples that you've provided over PHP, and they're good enough to have a better understanding on the type of data you're working with.

From these samples I saw that records.purdate and scores.date are the same, you basically copy purdate column into scores.date column. This might be a redundancy, but it's going to help us getting the startdate and enddate for each consecutive dates.

I need to mention first, I'm working on MySQL v5.7 and I use [MySQL Workbench 6.3](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) as IDE (It's been a long time since I used phpMyAdmin, but it should work with it too).

You'll need to create a stored procedure, if you don't know how to manage it within phpMyAdmin, just google it.

I'll provide you with a working one (tested) :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getConsecutiveInterval`(IN `selectRows` INT, IN `skippedRows` INT)
BEGIN
SET @selectRows = selectRows; 
SET @skippedRows = skippedRows; 

IF skippedRows = 0 THEN
SET @skippedRows = "";
ELSE 
SET @skippedRows = CONCAT(" , " , skippedRows);
END IF;

SET @q = CONCAT("SELECT concat(date_format(MIN(StartDate), '%Y-%m-%d'), '  /  ', date_format(MAX(EndDate), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Dates, AVG(Score)
FROM (
SELECT 
    a.purdate AS StartDate, 
    b.date AS EndDate, 
    b.score  AS Score
FROM records a 
LEFT JOIN scores b 
ON a.purdate = b.date AND a.personid = b.personid 
WHERE 
    a.personid = 133
AND a.status IN('P','T') 
AND b.score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY purdate ASC, score DESC 
LIMIT ", @selectRows, @skippedRows, " ", ") D;");

PREPARE ConsecutiveInterval FROM @q;
EXECUTE ConsecutiveInterval;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE ConsecutiveInterval;
END
```

This stored procedure is similar to your getConsecutiveInterval() function, except it's in MySQL.

How it works : 
you can call the stored procedure by

```
CALL getConsecutiveInterval(selectRows,skippedRows)
```

I've made a condition in stored procedure, if the skippedRows is 0, then it'll be an empty string. Otherwise the skippedRows will be always returned.

For instance, using the samples that you've provided :

```
CALL getConsecutiveInterval(4,0)
```

Will return :

```
'2015-07-11  /  2016-01-20', '4.25'
```

AND

```
CALL getConsecutiveInterval(4,1)
```

Will return

```
2016-01-30  /  2016-01-30   4.00
```

and so on.

The selectRows var is the $interval in your PHP and skippedRows is the $offset.

Then, from your PHP side, you can call it by :

```
$query = "CALL getConsecutiveInterval( " . $interval . " , "  . $offset .")";
```

This way, you'll only control the $interval and $offset integers with the output on PHP, the rest will be maintained by MySQL itself.

The $offset calculation will be the same as before :

```
$offset += $interval;
```

you can also change the stored procedure to be extended with more parameters such as personid, status ..etc. whatever parameter you need, you can always extend it.

For instance, I'll extend it with personid:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getConsecutiveInterval`(IN `selectRows` INT, IN `skippedRows` INT, IN personID INT)
BEGIN
SET @selectRows = selectRows; 
SET @skippedRows = skippedRows; 
SET @personid = personID;

IF skippedRows = 0 THEN
SET @skippedRows = "";
ELSE 
SET @skippedRows = CONCAT(" , " , skippedRows);
END IF;

IF personID > 0 THEN 
SET @personid = CONCAT(" AND a.personid = ",  personID); 
ELSE 
SET @personid = ""; 
END IF;

SET @q = CONCAT("SELECT concat(date_format(MIN(StartDate), '%Y-%m-%d'), '  /  ', date_format(MAX(EndDate), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Dates, AVG(Score)
FROM (
SELECT 
    a.purdate AS StartDate, 
    b.date AS EndDate, 
    b.score  AS Score
FROM records a 
LEFT JOIN scores b 
ON a.purdate = b.date AND a.personid = b.personid 
WHERE 
    a.status IN('P','T') 
AND b.score IS NOT NULL ", @personid, " ORDER BY purdate ASC, score DESC LIMIT ", @selectRows, @skippedRows, " ", ") D;");

PREPARE ConsecutiveInterval FROM @q;
EXECUTE ConsecutiveInterval;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE ConsecutiveInterval;
END
```

This would add another parameter to be called like this :

```
CALL getConsecutiveInterval(4,0, 133);
```

133 is the personid, if i changed it to 0, then the condition `a.personid = 133`

will be removed from the query, and i'll get a random data based on the table sort.

I hope this update will help you in your journey.

Comment: thank you for both of your suggestions. I have to admit your query is not something I am used to (mainly CRUD queries).  I tried your sql loop query directly in PHPmyadmin, but I get an error (testing only the SELECT query part outputs the expected values). Can the LOOP part be done with mysql 5.6??
and why is the sql interval variable set to 3 and not to 4??
About LIMITING the query, I the final function I will add a date range (i.e. selected startDay - selected endDay)

Comment: ad 2/ your PHP suggestion the Query part do you mean only the `SELECT 
        a.purdate, .......IN('P','T')  ORDER BY  purdate ASC, score DESC` 
and because of my wrong use of the word interval.

Comment: oh and ad2/ how is the $offset set for the first time?  I have edit my question with a simple function I have based on your php suggstion

Comment: Codes were untasted, and just for showcase scenario as I stated in my answer, I'll review them if you provide sample data, sqlfiddle is broken, just put the schema and some insert values codes in the post, to make sure they're work as excepted. As for the sql interval, you can set it to any number you want, I chose 3 by random. LIMIT will work with date range as well with no issues.

Comment: @user9191816 in PHP part, yes you inject the query as string (in Query part). $offset will be null for the first time, then after the first loop will have the $interval value, and it'll be adding it on each run. So if your $interval is 4. Your $offset will be null in the first run, and 4 in the second run, 8 in the third run ...etc.

Comment: @user9191816 you've got the PHP function right in your post. just set the $offset to 0 and your should be good to go.

Comment: @user9191816 you can add another parameter $personid and inject it to WHERE a.personid = 133. so you can request the function by $personid and $interval

Comment: i updated with schemas + sample data. I have also updated the php function in my post with the code I am testing with. Because of the randomnize of the sample data I can't expect the same averages.  I also added some screenshots to my post which hopefully make my question a bit clearer. 
The problem I have lays in the php loop I think and the rest if the data found can't be eqaully divided by interval. In my sample data I get 10 rows, so for interval 4 I expect 3 groups (2 intervals and a rest of 2) and when I set interval to 3 I expect 4 groups (3 intervals and a rest of 1). Regards

Comment: I think I found a minor mistake in your $interval $offset part, I had to change it into `$limitValues =  $offset. ", " . $interval . " ";` ( numbers are reversed when you use a comma) now I need to handle the rest value if it's not a "whole" interval? I am thinking of getting the $q outside the for loop so I can check for the total founds and use it to check how many $intervals / loops there are, but how to handle the rest???

Comment: `//Total Found Use To Divide by
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo 'Total Found: '.$num_rows.'<br/>';
        $numOfLoops = $num_rows/$interval;
        echo 'Num Of Loops: '. $numOfLoops.'<br/>';
// For loop will control the results sets divided by 4 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numOfLoops; $i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

Made a test example:

```
declare @selectedIntervalCount int=3, @selectedID int=1
declare @startDate date='2018-01-01',@endDate date='2018-01-31'
declare @data table(pID int,pDate date, statsValue int)
insert into @data(pID,pDate, statsValue)
values(1,'2018-01-01',1)
,(1,'2018-01-02',2),(1,'2018-01-03',3),(1,'2018-01-04',4)
,(1,'2018-01-05',5),(1,'2018-01-06',1),(1,'2018-01-07',2)
,(1,'2018-01-08',7),(1,'2018-01-09',4),(1,'2018-01-10',3)
,(1,'2018-01-11',8),(1,'2018-01-12',5),(1,'2018-01-13',3)


select tt1.tempIX/@selectedIntervalCount 'intervalIX', cast(min(tt1.pDate) as varchar)+' - '+cast(max(tt1.pDate) as varchar) 'interval', sum(tt1.statsValue)/cast(count(tt1.statsValue) as float) 'avgStatsValue' from( 
    select (row_number() over (order by pDate) -1) 'tempIX', t1.pDate, t1.statsValue 
    from @data t1
    where t1.pDate between @startDate and @endDate 
    and t1.pID=@selectedID
) tt1
group by tt1.tempIX/@selectedIntervalCount
order by tt1.tempIX/@selectedIntervalCount
```

output is:

```
intervalIX  interval    avgStatsValue
0   2018-01-01 - 2018-01-03 2
1   2018-01-04 - 2018-01-06 3,33333333333333
2   2018-01-07 - 2018-01-09 4,33333333333333
3   2018-01-10 - 2018-01-12 5,33333333333333
4   2018-01-13 - 2018-01-13 3
```

Comment: well I wrote this before your massive update but this should group every X dates in an interval and then get the average of the interval

Comment: tx, yes I have updated my question (sqlfiddle seems to be offline) and I will try if I can understand the query and translate it to my variables. 

btw how do you handle the rest value (ie say 4 consecutive days, but I have 15 rows found, how to handle the 3 days?)

Comment: the last 3 days will be grouped and averaged. but you can jusy do a count and force interval to contain eg 4 dates if the interval is 4

Comment: @user9191816 provided an example that I actually tested : ) changed the tempIX generation

Answer (score 0):

If your version of mysql provides windowing functions, the solutions seems rather simple.

```
select g.personid, min(g.date) dfrom, max(g.date) dto, avg(g.score) avgscore
  from (
    select s.*, floor((s.rn - 1) / 4) gn
      from (
        select scores.personid, scores.date, scores.score ,
           row_number() over (
             partition by scores.personid
             order by scores.date) as rn
         from scores
         join records
           on  scores.personid = records.personid
           and scores.date = records.purdate
         where records.status in ('T','P')
         order by personid, date
      ) s
  ) g
  group by g.personid, g.gn
  order by g.personid, g.gn;
```

with the data from the sql fiddle, this gives:

```
+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| personid | dfrom      | dto        | avgscore |
+----------+------------+------------+----------+
|      133 | 2015-07-11 | 2016-01-20 |   4.2500 |
|      133 | 2016-01-30 | 2016-09-28 |   3.0000 |
|      133 | 2016-10-02 | 2017-04-02 |   2.0000 |
|      145 | 2015-06-29 | 2016-06-30 |   3.0000 |
|      145 | 2016-10-24 | 2017-01-16 |   3.3333 |
|      156 | 2015-10-20 | 2015-12-17 |   2.0000 |
|      156 | 2015-12-19 | 2016-05-21 |   3.0000 |
|      156 | 2016-05-25 | 2016-10-16 |   4.7500 |
|      156 | 2017-01-30 | 2017-01-30 |   4.0000 |
+----------+------------+------------+----------+
```